# Wobbly effect in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ccsm

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 but Wobbly effect is not there.. I need that effect.. I searched CCSM but the option to enable is not there. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just installed CCSM and check the option with Wobbly Windows is there. Have you tried installing plugin extra?

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Comment: Thanks it worked .. But when I open a new window it is not working.. it works only when I move my mouse holding left click on mouse

Comment: Wobbly windows is an effect for dragging windows. It has no effect on Window opening. If you want to change the window opening/closing behaviour you need to modify "Animations" which you can find under "Effects" or simply typing "Animations" in the CCSM search (without quotes)